# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0, but Angular version 11.2.8 was found instead. how to solve this?

Tags: angular, angular11, angular13

This is my npm and cli versions.

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.4
Node: 16.14.0
OS: win32 x64
np: 8.3.1
```

error:

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0, but Angular version 11.2.8 was found instead

Comment: Install another version of node, possible with https://www.npmjs.com/package/n, or update your angular project to use angular 13

Comment: What command are you running? `ng build` in a project? If yes, which Angular version does this project run?